# Word boundaries in android pattern not working

Tags: java, android, regex, boundary

I have a pattern in Android Pattern

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b"+name+"\\b");
```

But this pattern doesn't find the names in text that contains dots or emojy or other things? How can I find the name in a string text?

Comment: Remove `\b`s, or use `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)"+Pattern.quote(name)+"(?!\\S)");`

Comment: but if i remove the \b i cant get the boundary of the word 
i am tryibg the second one and its the same thing 
the name in the string may include emojies  slashes dots and any other thingd

Comment: The problem here is with your definition of a word boundary. `\b` is a place between digits/letters/underscores and the rest of chars, or at the start/end and the next/preceding digit/letter/underscore. Perhaps, you want to only match "words" in between whitespaces, that is why  I suggest the second approach. Also, `"(?<!\\S)"` can be replaced with `"(?<!\\w)"` and `(?!\\S)` with `(?!\\w)` to emulate `\b`s in an unambiguous way.

Comment: the name that i search in the text may be  = "fjhsj455kd.,j"anything

Comment: Then how do you define *word boundaries*?

Comment: e.g 
i have name = "lovely.15"
string text = " hi lovely.15 how are you "

how to find the name inside the text ?!

Comment: With `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)"+Pattern.quote(name)+"(?!\\S)");`

Comment: oki now with arabic names
if the name is " يوسف ع " and the text is " يوسف عار " 
the problem without bondary will cach the name i dont want to cach it in this case

Comment: @NuWrssAzZam Consider updating your question, and adding examples of what you want to match.